# How can I extract the top words from a string in my dataframe column?

Tags: python, data-mining, data-cleaning

I have a column in my dataframe which is in a string providing description of a product. For example : This is a shirt. It is blue in color. The sizes available are large, small. The shirt is tight fit.

I want to extract the keywords from this description like shirt, blue, large, small, sizes, tight etc.

I am using python. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If the words are all short and like the one you mentioned, I think you're pretty done with just removing the stopwords. It is a simple text cleaning of the most frequent words that don't bring additional meaning to the text.
Let me know.